# Extract select data from A1 into B1

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I've 6,000 rows of data with each individual cell like this:

```
Residential for sale: 
31
Avg. asking price:
£414,353
Avg. sale listing age:
14 weeks
```

It's unstyled, and one long string. I'm trying to strip out the `Residential for sale` value (`31`), `Avg. asking price:` value (`£414,353`), `Avg. sale listing age:` value (`14 weeks`) into their own cells for each line. For instance, if the example data was in `A1` the above extracted data would be in `B1`, `C1`,`D1`.

I've been looking into Regex as a way to do this, but couldn't find a way to do it in Google Drive, so far I've only found a VBA way which won't work in Google Drive.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the solution for Excel or Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: Google spreasheets please - the reason i put both is becuase i was trying to do it using a function that would work in both, rather than using VBA or Google scripts

Comment: I don't do Google Spreadsheets, I was just trying to clarify whether this was for Excel or not. But the VBA solution can probably be ported: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

Comment: Scratch that - but have a look at the Split function: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Please try in B1:

```
=query(split(A1,char(10)),"select Col2, Col4, Col6")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enter the following in B2, it will extract the numbers you want. Howeve, it returns them in columns D, G, and K. I do not know why.
    =split(lower(A1),"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz: ")

I updated the above formula as pnuts suggested. It is better. Thanks.
The below script seems to solve all the problems (blank columns and missing weeks). The currency can be formatted to British pounds from the format menu.

```
function splitData(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lr = sheet.getLastRow()
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A"+lr);
val = range.getValues()
var s=[]
   for(var i=0;i<val.length;i++){
      var t = val[i][0]
      s[i]=t.split(":")
    }
 for(var x=0;x<s.length;x++){
     for(var y=1;y<3;y++){
       s[x][y] =s[x][y].replace(/\D/g,"")
    }}
var finalArr = [] 
for (var i = 0; i <lr; i++) {
  finalArr[i] = [];
for (var j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {        
  finalArr[i].push(s[i][j]);
}
}
 sheet.getRange(1,2,lr,3).setValues(finalArr)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous solutions and assuming your data starts in first row of col A, also try:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A:A), regexextract(A:A, {"(\d+)","price:\n(.+)\n", "\n(.+)$"}),))
```

and see if that works ?

Answer (score 0):

=split(substitute(substitute(substitute(A7,"Residential for sale: ",""),"Avg. asking price:",";"),"
Avg. sale listing age:",";"),";")

Basically what I did with formula, is replace the first heading "residential for sale" with a null value using "", then I transformed the other two into ";" delimiters so you can wrap the whole thing in your split formula.

Answer (score 0):

if your original data does have all those new lines, then even better you can try this:
    `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,".*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)$")`